# GCC: Is it possible to extract compiler options from an object file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect GCC compile-time flags of a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189350/detect-gcc-compile-time-flags-of-a-binary)

If I compile a source file into an object file with gcc using some set of options, like so:

```
$ gcc -c -option1 -option2 ... -optionN -o foo.o foo.c
```

Is it possible to later extract the list of options used `(-option1, -option2, ... -optionN)` to compile foo.o from itself somehow?